# Python SQL/JSON mismatched input 'ON' expecting 'EOF'

Tags: python, sql, json

im using an SDK which can send sql queries via JSON, however I am getting the error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 893, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: mismatched input 'ON' expecting 'EOF' for url: https://solarwinds-orion:17778/SolarWinds/InformationService/v3/Json/Query
```

this is the code im using:

```
swis = SwisClient(hostname, username, password, verify=v_path)   
query = """
SELECT NodeID,NodeName,IPAddress,IP,IP_Address,NodeIPAddresses 
FROM Orion.Nodes ON
    inner join Orion.NodesCustomProperties CP
    on ON.NodeID = CP.NodeID
WHERE CP.smartnet = 1
"""
results = swis.query(query)
```

and this is a link to the schemas

customproperties - http://solarwinds.github.io/OrionSDK/schema/Orion.NodesCustomProperties.html
nodes - http://solarwinds.github.io/OrionSDK/schema/Orion.Nodes.html

From what ive searched on inner joins that query should be fine?

Comment: `ON` is a reserved keyword. use a different table alias. also use table aliases before columns being selected to avoid ambiguous column name error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your table alias from `ON` to something else and you should be fine:

```sql
SELECT NodeID      -- You should also be using the appropriate table alias
      ,NodeName    -- for each of these columns.
      ,IPAddress
      ,IP
      ,IP_Address
      ,NodeIPAddresses 
FROM Orion.Nodes N
    inner join Orion.NodesCustomProperties CP
        on N.NodeID = CP.NodeID
WHERE CP.smartnet = 1
```

This is an error because `on` is a reserved keyword like `select` or `and` which has significance to the sql compiler.

Comment: ahh, makes perfect sense!